# stack apply not working for raster with date as layer names

Tags: r

I have a raster brick that has year and month as layer names.

```
head(names(raster))
[1] "X1979.06" "X1979.07" "X1979.08" "X1979.09" "X1980.06" "X1980.07"
```

I want to get the annual sum values but my code returns `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA`.

```
indices <- format(as.Date(names(raster), format = "X%Y.%m"), format = "%Y")
ras_sum<-stackApply(raster, indices, sum)
```

it could be because of missing date value as this code does work on such raster bricks.
any idea how to resolve this error ?

Comment: `format(as.Date(paste(names(raster), "01"), format = "X%Y.%m %d"), format = "%Y")`